# Open Redis port for remote connections

Tags: ubuntu, redis

I can ping pong Redis on the server:

```
# redis-cli ping
PONG
```

But remotely, I got problems:

```
$ src/redis-cli -h REMOTE.IP ping
Could not connect to Redis at REMOTE.IP:6379: Connection refused
```

In config, I got the standard port:

```
# Accept connections on the specified port, default is 6379.
# If port 0 is specified Redis will not listen on a TCP socket.
port 6379
```

So maybe I should open port 6379 on the remote Ubuntu machine? How do I do it?

Comment: redis is not listening on the remote machine?

Comment: maybe, how to check it

Comment: Have you disabled ufw?

Answer (score 301, accepted):

Did you set the bind option to allow remote access on the redis server?

Before (file `/etc/redis/redis.conf`)

```
bind 127.0.0.1
```

After

```
bind 0.0.0.0
```

and run `sudo service redis-server restart` to restart the server. If that's not the problem, you might want to check any firewalls that might block the access.

**Important:** If you don't use a firewall (iptables, ufw..) to control who connects to the port in use, ANYONE can connect to this Redis instance. Without using [Redis' `AUTH`](http://redis.io/commands/auth) that means anyone can access/change/delete your data. Be safe!

Comment: in config file I added string `bind 0.0.0.0` after string 
`bind 127.0.0.1`. Restarted redis. And now can connect remotly.

Comment: Is there any difference if we use `bind 0.0.0.0` alone vs `bind 127.0.0.1 0.0.0.0`

Comment: @Nyxynyx 0.0.0.0 binds to all adapters, so it's unnecessary. Shouldn't make a difference, though.

Comment: Is it secure to open redis to any ip calls? How can we restricted accessing redis from only certain IPs?

Comment: @brsbilgic That should probably be done using a firewall. Check out iptables or UFW.

Comment: @MildlySerious thanks a lot. We have wasted almost 2 weeks figuring out whether firewall or network or some other issue. But this change worked like champ.

Answer (score 30):

For me, I needed to do the following:

1- Comment out `bind 127.0.0.1`

2- Change `protected-mode` to `no`

3- Protect my server with `iptables` (https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-implement-a-basic-firewall-template-with-iptables-on-ubuntu-14-04)

Comment: I had to use bind 0.0.0.0. "bind 127.0.0.1" didn't work for me. I didn't need to set "protected-mode" to "no". Warning: Don't leave empty space before the "bind" or the server won't start. Note: I'm using the windows port of Redis

Answer (score 19):

**Bind & protected-mode** both are the essential steps.
But if **ufw** is enabled then you will have to make redis port allow in ufw.

1. Check **ufw** status `ufw status` if `Status: active` then allow redis-port `ufw allow 6379`
2. `vi /etc/redis/redis.conf`
3. Change the `bind 127.0.0.1` to `bind 0.0.0.0`
4. change the `protected-mode yes` to `protected-mode no`

Comment: the `ufw` was the difference for me.

Comment: I missed the protected-mode option, this answer should get more votes for others not to miss this option too :)

Comment: @Rutger agree :)

Answer (score 7):

A quick note that doing this without further securing your Redis server is not a good idea as it can leave you open to attack. Be sure to also implement AUTH or otherwise secure that. See http://redis.io/topics/security for details.

Answer (score 5):

1- Comment out bind 127.0.0.1

2- set requirepass yourpassword

then check if the firewall blocked your port

iptables -L -n

service iptables stop

Answer (score 5):

Another possibly helpful note.

**Redis can be bound to multiple IPs** - that's very helpful when you don't want to open it to entire world (`0.0.0.0`) but only make it accessible in local networks.

1. `sudo nano /etc/redis/redis.conf`
2. add your local network IP to the end of `bind` setting:

`bind 127.0.0.1 10.0.0.1`

3. restart the service: `sudo service redis-server restart`

Now you can easily access redis from other computers in same network, e.g.
`redis-cli -h 10.0.0.1`

Comment: thank you! very very helpful the suggestion 2 :-) that is exactly the solution I was looking for

Comment: Hi This is should be the most accepted answer.  Although bind 0.0.0.0 will work, it exposes your server to security threat, even if you have firewall. Technically  you allow to any server or pc connected to your LAN to access this server

Answer (score 4):

1. Open the file at location `/etc/redis.conf`
2. Comment out `bind 127.0.0.1`
3. Restart Redis service:

   ```
    sudo systemctl restart redis.service
   ```
4. Disable Firewalld:

   ```
    systemctl disable firewalld
   ```
5. Stop Firewalld:

   ```
    systemctl stop firewalld
   ```

Then try:

```
redis-cli -h 192.168.0.2(ip) -a redis(username)
```

Answer (score 3):

A quick note that if you are using AWS ec2 instance then there is one more extra step that I believe is also mandatory. I missed the step-3 and it took me whole day to figure out to add an inbound rule to security group

Step 1(as previous): in your redis.conf change bind 127.0.0.1 to bind 0.0.0.0

Step2(as previous):  in your redis.conf change protected-mode yes to protected-mode no

#### important for Amazon Ec2 Instance:

Step3: In your current ec2 machine go to the security group. add an inbound rule 
for custom TCP with 6379 port and select option "use from anywhere".

Comment: Do not allow from anywhere, allow from specific IP's only. It's a big security issue.

Answer (score 2):

1. Open $REDIS_HOME/redis.conf and uncomment `requirepass -YOUR-PASSWORD-HERE-` and write down your password in the specified lines.
2. Login to redis using redis-cli and verify your password in the database using `auth -YOUR-PASSWORD-HERE-` command.
3. Disable protected mode by changing its string in $REDIS_HOME/redis.conf to `protected-mode no`.
4. Search for all bind ports values and comment all of them. Just add `bind 0.0.0.0` to $REDIS_HOME/redis.conf file.
5. Disable your firewall or open redis port.
6. Start redis using `./redis-server $REDIS_HOME/redis.conf`.
7. Check the configuration via `./redis-cli -h -YOUR-IP- -a -YOUR-PASSWORD-HERE-`.
8. Check the configuration via `./redis-cli -h -YOUR-IP- ping`.

Comment: Please don't ever give the advice "Disable your firewall".

Answer (score 1):

> In my case, I'm using redis-stable

```
Go to redis-stable path 
 cd /home/ubuntu/software/redis-stable
```

> Open the redis.conf

```
vim redis.conf
```

> Change the `bind 127.0.0.1` to `bind 0.0.0.0`
>
> change the `protected-mode yes` to  `protected-mode no`
>
> Restart the redis-server:

```
/etc/init.d/redis-server stop
 redis-server redis.conf
```