# Can't access Redis-Server running on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS externally

Tags: ubuntu, networking, redis, redis-server

I followed the thread here: [open redis port for remote connections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19091087/open-redis-port-for-remote-connections) (and various other suggestions) in an attempt to make the redis-server running on my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS accessible externally (ie: outside my home network).  However, no success.

When I enter "sudo netstat -ntlp | grep LISTEN", I get the following results (ie: redis-server appears to be listening to 0.0.0.0:6379 as expected):

```
    tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6942          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2653/java       
    tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:6379            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      13325/redis-server 
    tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5037          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      13759/adb       
    tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:63342         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2653/java       
    tcp        0      0 127.0.1.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2067/dnsmasq    
    tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1567/cupsd      
    tcp6       0      0 :::3689                 :::*                    LISTEN      2483/rhythmbox  
    tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN      1567/cupsd
```

Entering "sudo ufw status" produces the following (ie: firewall is off):

```
    Status: inactive
```

I restart the server using "sudo service redis-server restart", which simply outputs the following (ie: no errors show):

```
    Stopping redis-server: redis-server.
    Starting redis-server: redis-server.
```

When I use "redis-cli -h IP-ADDRESS ping" I am able to access the redis server (ie: get PONG as response) given I use the IP address of 'localhost', 127.0.0.1, or 192.168.1.106 (internal network IP).  However, I get an error  when I use my external/remote IP address (one identified by Googling "My ip address"), which gives me the error:

```
    Could not connect to Redis at <Remote-IP>:6379: Connection refused
```

Note that I face the same issue whether my computer is directly connected to the internet (no router), or via a router which has port forwarding set up.

Note that I'd installed most recent redis-server in apt-repository ppa:chris-lea/redis-server.

Your help and suggestions are much appreciated.